# variable 'x' of type 'Product' referenced from scope, but it is not defined

Tags: c#, lambda, subsonic3, linq-expressions

I have a class named `Product` in class library project. I am using `SubSonic SimpleRepository` to persist objects. I have a method as follows in `Product` class:

```
public static IList<Product> Load(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expression)
{
    var rep=RepoHelper.GetRepo("ConStr");
    var products = rep.Find(expression);
    return products.ToList();
}
```

I'm calling this function like this:

```
private void BindData()
{
    var list = Product.Load(x => x.Active);//Active is of type bool
    rptrItems.DataSource = list;
    rptrItems.DataBind();
}
```

Calling `Load` from `BindData` throws the exception:

```
variable 'x' of type 'Product' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

How can I resolve this.

EDIT:- by stepping through `SubSonic` code I found that the error is thrown by this function

```
private static Expression Evaluate(Expression e)
{
    if(e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        return e;
    Type type = e.Type;
    if(type.IsValueType)
        e = Expression.Convert(e, typeof(object));
    Expression<Func<object>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(e);
    Func<object> fn = lambda.Compile(); //THIS THROWS EXCEPTION
    return Expression.Constant(fn(), type);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in SubSonic. (@Kobi: No.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After banging my head on the wall for many days and even asking Jon Skeet for help, I found out the problem.

The problem actually is with SubSonic (@Timwi was right). It is right in this line:

```
var list = Product.Load(x => x.Active);//Active is of type bool
```

After I changed it to:

```
var list = Product.Load(x => x.Active==true);
```

all was well.

Comment: Do you know why this was a problem?

Comment: This is the top hit for the error message, unfortunately, as this isn't really an answer to the issue most are having, including me and @user1039462.  For me, the issue was that you must use the same ParameterExpression *everywhere*.  It is **not enough** that the ParameterExpression has the same variable name.  I believed it was, but I'd get the exception about scope because I wasn't the same instance of ParameterExpression in my expression tree and in the root LambdaExpression.

Comment: @Will the issue was in SubSonic. It was not setting the variable value  if not explicitly set.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: I know, but the error message is the same, and this question is the top hit for the error message :/

Comment: I'm just leaving this comment here, since it's top hit for the error message. If you are using ServiceStack.OrmLite and have this exception trying to `Select` something from DB, please note that null check is properly done using `NullableVar != null`, not by `NullableVar.HasValue`